Pandas dataframe: interpolate with regular time intervals
My input dataframe looks like this:
ts = ['2008-01-02 06:50:00', '2008-01-02 06:51:00',  '2008-01-02 06:53:00', 
      '2008-01-02 06:54:00',  '2008-01-02 06:57:00', '2008-01-02 06:58:00', '2008-01-02 07:39:00']
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts':ts, 'a':a, 'b':b})

                ts      a   b
0  2008-01-02 06:50:00  1  11
1  2008-01-02 06:51:00  2  22
2  2008-01-02 06:53:00  3  33
3  2008-01-02 06:54:00  4  44
4  2008-01-02 06:57:00  5  55
5  2008-01-02 06:58:00  6  66
6  2008-01-02 07:39:00  7  77

I want to insert synthetic rows with 1 min intervals such that the value of a is from the previously seen row, and b is 0, but only if the gap is smaller than 30 mins:
                ts      a   b
0  2008-01-02 06:50:00  1  11
1  2008-01-02 06:51:00  2  22
2  2008-01-02 06:52:00  2  0
3  2008-01-02 06:53:00  3  33
4  2008-01-02 06:54:00  4  44
5  2008-01-02 06:55:00  4  0
6  2008-01-02 06:56:00  4  0
7  2008-01-02 06:57:00  5  55
8  2008-01-02 06:58:00  6  66
9  2008-01-02 07:39:00  7   77


Are the values in a unique?

One option would be to resample:
out = df.set_index('ts').resample('1min').ffill().reset_index()
out.loc[out['a'].duplicated(), 'b'] = 0

If the values in a are not necessarily unique:
tmp = df.set_index('ts')
out = (tmp[['a']].resample('1min').ffill()
          .join(tmp['b'], how='left').reset_index()
          .fillna({'b': 0})
      )

You can also reindex:
a, b = df['ts'].agg(['min', 'max'])

out = (df.set_index('ts')
         .reindex(pd.date_range(a, b, freq='1min'))
         .rename_axis('ts').reset_index()
      )
out['a'] = out['a'].ffill()
out['b'] = out['b'].fillna(0)

Output:
                   ts  a   b
0 2008-01-02 06:50:00  1  11
1 2008-01-02 06:51:00  2  22
2 2008-01-02 06:52:00  2   0
3 2008-01-02 06:53:00  3  33
4 2008-01-02 06:54:00  4  44
5 2008-01-02 06:55:00  4   0
6 2008-01-02 06:56:00  4   0
7 2008-01-02 06:57:00  5  55
8 2008-01-02 06:58:00  6  66

updated example: partial reindexing
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])

a, b = df['ts'].iloc[:-1].agg(['min', 'max'])
idx = pd.date_range(a, b, freq='1min').union(df['ts'].iloc[-1:], sort=False)

out = (df.set_index('ts')
         .reindex(idx)
         .rename_axis('ts').reset_index()
      )
out['a'] = out['a'].ffill()
out['b'] = out['b'].fillna(0)

Output:
                   ts    a     b
0 2008-01-02 06:50:00  1.0  11.0
1 2008-01-02 06:51:00  2.0  22.0
2 2008-01-02 06:52:00  2.0   0.0
3 2008-01-02 06:53:00  3.0  33.0
4 2008-01-02 06:54:00  4.0  44.0
5 2008-01-02 06:55:00  4.0   0.0
6 2008-01-02 06:56:00  4.0   0.0
7 2008-01-02 06:57:00  5.0  55.0
8 2008-01-02 06:58:00  6.0  66.0
9 2008-01-02 07:39:00  7.0  77.0

groupby resampling
group = df['ts'].diff().gt('30min').cumsum().values

tmp = df.set_index('ts')
out = (tmp[['a']]
          .groupby(group)
          .resample('1min').ffill()
          .join(tmp['b'], how='left').reset_index(1)
          .fillna({'b': 0})
      )

Output:
                   ts  a     b
0 2008-01-02 06:50:00  1  11.0
0 2008-01-02 06:51:00  2  22.0
0 2008-01-02 06:52:00  2   0.0
0 2008-01-02 06:53:00  3  33.0
0 2008-01-02 06:54:00  4  44.0
0 2008-01-02 06:55:00  4   0.0
0 2008-01-02 06:56:00  4   0.0
0 2008-01-02 06:57:00  5  55.0
0 2008-01-02 06:58:00  6  66.0
1 2008-01-02 07:39:00  7  77.0


Sorry, I made a late update to the original question: how about if we don't want to fill (interpolate) gaps that are above certain value, e.g. above 30 mins? Like the last row that I added, there's no interpolation before it. Thanks

@BaronYugovich then go with the reindex approach, you can craft the desired index. See the update

I also added an option for groupby resampling based on a threshold. Actually, you have so many options, depending on the exact expected logic

You can create groupings based on non-contiguous 30 minute intervals
and apply your resampling logic within those. I added some more data to your example to demonstrate the 30min window gropings a bit better.
import pandas as pd

ts = [
    '2008-01-02 06:50:00', '2008-01-02 06:51:00',  '2008-01-02 06:53:00',
    '2008-01-02 06:54:00',  '2008-01-02 06:57:00', '2008-01-02 06:58:00',
    '2008-01-02 07:39:00', '2008-01-02 07:42:00', '2008-01-02 07:45:00'
]
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': pd.to_datetime(ts), 'a':  a, 'b':  b})

print(
    df
    .set_index('ts')
    .astype({'b': 'Int64'})
    .groupby(
        (df['ts'].diff() > pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).cumsum().values
    )
    .resample('1min')
    .agg({'a': 'ffill', 'b': 'asfreq'})
    .fillna({'b': 0})
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)
#                      a   b
# ts
# 2008-01-02 06:50:00  1  11
# 2008-01-02 06:51:00  2  22
# 2008-01-02 06:52:00  2   0
# 2008-01-02 06:53:00  3  33
# 2008-01-02 06:54:00  4  44
# 2008-01-02 06:55:00  4   0
# 2008-01-02 06:56:00  4   0
# 2008-01-02 06:57:00  5  55
# 2008-01-02 06:58:00  6  66
# 2008-01-02 07:39:00  7  77
# 2008-01-02 07:40:00  7   0
# 2008-01-02 07:41:00  7   0
# 2008-01-02 07:42:00  8  88
# 2008-01-02 07:43:00  8   0
# 2008-01-02 07:44:00  8   0
# 2008-01-02 07:45:00  9  99

